# unitisation of a unital $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I feel a little confused about the conclusion of  unitisation of unial $C^*$algebras.There are two different statements .
1. If $A$ is unital,then the only unitisation is $A$ itself.
2.If $A$ is unital,then $\tilde{A}$ is $*$-isomorphic to $A\oplus \Bbb C$.
 The above conclusions are from different reference books. Which conclusion is correct?

Comment: Presumably the two books use different definitions of "unitisation".  Check their definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the definition of unitization from your first reference is something like:

> A unitization of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is an embedding of $A$ as an essential ideal in a unital $C^*$-algebra.

In this case, if $A$ is unital then the only unitization of $A$ is itself.  Indeed, if $A,B$ are unital and $A\subset B$ is an essential ideal, then $(1_B-1_A)a=0$ for all $a\in A$, so $1_B=1_A$ and it follows that $B=A$.

---

The definition from your second reference is probably more standard.  In this case, the unitization of $A$ is $\tilde A=A\oplus\mathbb C$ as a vector space, with multiplication and involution
$$(a,\lambda)(b,\mu)=(ab+\mu a+\lambda b,\lambda\mu),\qquad (a,\lambda)^*=(a^*,\overline\lambda),$$
and the norm of $(a,\lambda)$ is the maximum of $|\lambda|$ and $\sup\{\|ab+\lambda b\|:\|b\|\leq1\}$.  In this case, if $A$ is unital, then the algebra homomorphism $\tilde A\to A\oplus\mathbb C$ given by $(a,\lambda)\mapsto(a+\lambda 1_A,\lambda)$, is a $*$-isomorphism.

---

To summarize, both statements are correct, but the references use different definitions.