# Surjectivity of unitization functor of C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra.

**Question:** Is $A$ isomorphic to the unitization of a $C^*$-algebra $A_0$?

*Clarification:* Here, I am using the functorial definition of unitization. The unitization of $A_0$ is the algebra with underlying vector space $A_0\oplus\mathbb C$ and norm
$$||(a,\lambda)\|=\max\Big\{|\lambda|,\sup_{\|b\|=1}\{\|ab+\lambda b\|\}\Big\}.$$

*Thoughts:* Suppose $A$ is commutative. Then by Gelfand duality, $A$ is isomorphic to $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$. So in the commutative case it would suffice that any such $X$ is the one-point compactification of some space $X_0$; but I'm not even sure if this is true.

Comment: The answer depends on the definition [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284106/unitisation-of-a-unital-c-algebra)

Comment: Thanks, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The algebra $A_0$ in question would necessarily be an ideal -- the multiplication you have on the unitization is
$$(a,\mu)(b,\nu) = (ab + \mu b + \nu a, \mu \nu).$$
Thus if $\mu$ or $\nu$ is 0, then the right component will be 0, i.e., $A_0$ is an ideal. Are there C*-algebras without proper ideals? (try $M_n$)

As for the commutative case, see [Which spaces can be seen as to be the one-point compactification of some other space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437097/which-spaces-can-be-seen-as-to-be-the-one-point-compactification-of-some-other-s).

Of course, the unitization you describe is a "minimal" unitization. However every unital C*-algebra $A$ is in fact the multiplier algebra of itself (which is in some sense a "maximal unitization" -- it corresponds to the Stone–Čech compactification in the commutative case).

Answer (score 2):

No, but if $A_0$ is unital, then $A\cong A_0 \oplus_\infty \mathbb{C}$ as $C^*$-algebras. The map
$$A_0\oplus_\infty \mathbb{C}\to A: (a, \lambda) \mapsto (a-\lambda 1_{A_0})+ \lambda 1_{A}$$
is an isomorphism of $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: What does $\oplus_\infty$ mean?

Comment: Max norm of the two Banach spaces

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: if $A=\mathbb C$, then you're saying $A_0$ is $\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C$ as a vector space? That doesn't fit inside $A$.

Comment: @geometricK Ah sorry, I misunderstood your notation. I thought $A_0$ is the $C^*$-algebra and $A$ is the unitisation. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The first time I came up with this question is when I learned K-theory. I realized that $B(H)$ cannot be such a C*-algebra.

If $A$ is the unitization of $B$, then we have a short exact sequence which is necessarily split:
$$0\rightarrow B\rightarrow A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\rightarrow0.$$
So by the split exactness of $K_0$, we have a split exact sequence:
$$0\rightarrow K_0(B)\rightarrow K_0(A)\rightarrow K_0(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow 0.$$
Or equivalently, $K_0(A)\cong K_0(B)\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.
The conclusion is: if $A$ is a unital C*-algebra whose $K_0$ group cannot admit $\mathbb{Z}$ as a direct summand, then $A$ cannot be a unitalization of another one.

For example, the Cuntz algebras (but they are also simple), $B(H)$, and more generally, $M(A\otimes\mathbb{K})$, where $M$ denotes the multiplier algebra, $\mathbb{K}$ is the algebra of compact operators on a infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space.